# configurable products are not updating in cart

Tags: configurable-product, cart

please visit this [link](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/wtest4.html)

add this configurable product to cart ,go to cart page and try to update the quantity , for example more than 1.

but in cart page, if we try to edit the quantity, **its not updating more than one**. but required number of quantity is available in backend.

```
Error : Number of quantity not available.
```

we installed one extension This error is coming from an extension. If we remove the extension, it will work fine.but we need that extension for some purpose. This is **observer.php** of the extension.

```
<?php
Class Company_Extension_Model_Observer
{
    /*after update cart*/   
    public function cartUpdate($observer) {
        $db = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
        $cart = $observer->getCart()->getQuote()->getAllItems();
        $cart_data =  Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
        $info = $observer->getInfo();
        foreach($cart_data as $item) {
            $current_qty=$info[$item->getId()]['qty'];
            $productid= $item->getProductId();
            $mpassignproductId=0;
            foreach($item->getOptions() as $option) {
                $temp=unserialize($option['value']);
                if($temp['mpassignproduct_id'])
                    $mpassignproductId=$temp['mpassignproduct_id'];
            }
            if($mpassignproductId) {
                $productdetail=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->load($mpassignproductId);
                $price=$productdetail->getPrice();
                $avlqty=$productdetail->getQty();
                $seller=$productdetail->getSellerId();

                $diff=$avlqty-$current_qty;
                if($diff>0) {
                    $item->setCustomPrice($price);
                    $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
                    $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
                } else if($diff<=0) {
                    if($current_qty > $avlqty) {
                        $item->setCustomPrice($price);
                        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
                        $item->setQty($avlqty);
                        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addNotice('Number of quantity not available.');
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $adminAvlQty=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->getAssignProDetails($productid);
                if($current_qty >  $adminAvlQty['sellerqty']) {
                    $item->setQty($adminAvlQty['sellerqty']);
                    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addNotice('Number of quantity not available.');
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /*after product added to cart*/ 
    public function productCart(Varien_Event_Observer $obs) {
        $cart_data =  Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

        $item = $obs->getQuoteItem();
        $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
        $db = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
        $productid=$item->getProductId();           
        foreach ($cart_data as $cart) { 
            if($cart->getProductId()==$productid){
                $quantity=$cart->getQty();
            }
        }
        $productid= $item->getProductId();
        $mpassignproductId=0;
        foreach($item->getOptions() as $option) {
            $temp=unserialize($option['value']);
            if($temp['mpassignproduct_id'])
                $mpassignproductId=$temp['mpassignproduct_id'];

        }
        if($mpassignproductId) {
            $productdetail=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->load($mpassignproductId);
            $price=$productdetail->getPrice();
            $avlqty=$productdetail->getQty();
            $seller=$productdetail->getSellerId();

            $diff=$avlqty-$quantity;
            if($diff>0) {
                $item->setCustomPrice($price);
                $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
                $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
            } else if($diff<=0) {
                if($quantity > $avlqty) {
                    $item->setCustomPrice($price);
                    $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
                    $item->setQty($avlqty);
                    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addNotice('Number of quantity not available.');
                }
            }
        } else {
            $adminAvlQty=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->getAssignProDetails($productid);
            if($quantity >  $adminAvlQty['sellerqty']) {
                $item->setQty($adminAvlQty['sellerqty']);
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addNotice('Number of quantity not available.');
            }
        }
    }

    public function productUpdateCart(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) { 
        $item=$observer->getItem();
        $proprice=$item->getProduct()->getPrice();
        $item->setCustomPrice($proprice);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($proprice);
        $item->save();  
    }

    public function afterPlaceOrder1($observer) { 
        $lastOrderId=$observer->getOrder()->getId();
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($lastOrderId);
        $ordered_items = $order->getAllItems();
        foreach ($ordered_items as $item) {
            $options=$item->getProductOptions();
            $productId=$item->getProductId();
            $mpassignproductId=$options['info_buyRequest']['mpassignproduct_id'];
            if($mpassignproductId) {
                $collect=Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('mageproid',array('eq'=>$productId))
                    ->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',array('eq'=>$lastOrderId));
                foreach($collect as $val) {
                    $slqty=$val['magequantity'];
                    $saleslistId=$val['autoid'];
                }
                $mpassignModel=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->load($mpassignproductId);

                if($saleslistId) {
                    $saleslistModel=Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->load($saleslistId);
                    $saleslistModel->setMageproownerid($mpassignModel->getSellerId());
                    $saleslistModel->setMpassignproductId($mpassignproductId);
                    $saleslistModel->save();

                    $asqt=$mpassignModel->getQty();
                    $nasqt = $asqt-$slqty;
                    $mpassignModel->setQty($nasqt);
                    $mpassignModel->save();
                } 
            }
        }
    }
    /*Pending................................on product delete from seller*/
    public function deleteProductCheck($observer) {
        $productid=$observer->getId();
        $collection=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')
                        ->getCollection()
                        ->addFieldToFilter('product_id',array('eq'=>$productid))
                        ->addFieldToFilter('qty',array('gt'=>0));
        $collection->setOrder("price","ASC");
        if(count($collection)>0) {
            foreach($collection as $assignproduct) {
                $collectionpro=Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()
                        ->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$productid));
                foreach($collectionpro as $row) {
                    $row->setUserid($assignproduct->getSellerId());
                    $row->save();
                    // set qty to product
                    $data=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->getAssignProDetails($productid);

                    $_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productid);
                    $_product->setPrice($assignproduct->getPrice());
                    $_product->save();

                    $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($productid);
                    $stockItem->setProductId($productid)->setStockId(1);
                    $savedStock = $stockItem->save();
                    $stockItem->load($savedStock->getId())->setQty($data['assignqty'])->save();
                    $stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 1); 
                    $savedStock = $stockItem->save();
                }
                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setIsAssing($assignproduct->getMpassignproductId());
                $assignproduct->delete();
                break;
            }
        } else {
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setIsAssing(0);
        }
    }

    //when admin will the delete the product
    public function DeleteProduct($observer) { 
        $collection = Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->getCollection()
                                ->addFieldToFilter('product_id ',$observer->getProduct()->getId());
        foreach($collection as $data){          
            Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->load($data['mpassignproduct_id'])->delete();         
        }       
    }
}
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
/**
 * @category   company
 * @package    company_Mpassignproduct
 * @author     ModuleCreator
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */
 -->
<config>
    <modules>
        <company_Mpassignproduct>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </company_Mpassignproduct>
    </modules>


    <!-- ssl -->
    <frontend>
    <secure_url>
        <company_Mpassignproduct>/mpassignproduct/index/index/</company_Mpassignproduct>
        <company_Mpassignproduct>/mpassignproduct/index/mpassignproductlist/</company_Mpassignproduct>
    </secure_url>
</frontend>


<!-- ssl  end-->

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <mpassignproduct>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>company_Mpassignproduct</module>
                    <frontName>mpassignproduct</frontName>
                </args>
            </mpassignproduct>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mpassignproduct>
                    <file>mpassignproduct.xml</file>
                </mpassignproduct>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <company_Mpassignproduct>
                    <files>
                      <mpassignproduct>company_Mpassignproduct.csv</mpassignproduct>
                    </files>
                </company_Mpassignproduct>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </frontend>
        <admin>
              <routers>
                    <mpassignproduct>
                        <use>admin</use>
                        <args>
                            <module>company_Mpassignproduct</module>
                            <frontName>mpassignproduct</frontName>
                        </args>
                    </mpassignproduct>
            </routers>
        </admin>
        <adminhtml>
            <acl>
                <resources>
                    <all>
                       <title>Allow Everything</title>
                    </all>
                    <admin>
                        <children>
                            <company_Mpassignproduct>
                                <title>Mpassignproduct Module</title>
                                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            </company_Mpassignproduct>
                        </children>
                    </admin>
                </resources>
            </acl>
            <layout>
                <updates>
                      <mpassignproduct>
                         <file>mpassignproduct.xml</file>
                      </mpassignproduct>
                  </updates>
              </layout>
        </adminhtml>   
    <global>
    <events>
      <catalog_product_delete_after>
          <observers>
             <company_Mpassignproduct_Model_Observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>company_Mpassignproduct_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>DeleteProduct</method>
             </company_Mpassignproduct_Model_Observer>
         </observers>
      </catalog_product_delete_after>
      <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
               <observers>
                   <company_Mpassignproduct_Model_Observer>
                      <type>singleton</type>
                      <class>company_Mpassignproduct_Model_Observer</class>
                      <method>productCart</method>
                   </company_Mpassignproduct_Model_Observer>
               </observers>
           </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
      <checkout_cart_update_items_after>
          <observers>
              <company_Mpassignproduct_Model_Observer>
                  <type>singleton</type>
                  <class>company_Mpassignproduct_Model_Observer</class>
                  <method>cartUpdate</method>
              </company_Mpassignproduct_Model_Observer>
          </observers>
      </checkout_cart_update_items_after>
      <checkout_cart_update_item_complete>
          <observers>
              <company_Mpassignproduct_Model_Observer>
                  <type>singleton</type>
                  <class>company_Mpassignproduct_Model_Observer</class>
                  <method>productUpdateCart</method> 
              </company_Mpassignproduct_Model_Observer>
          </observers>
      </checkout_cart_update_item_complete>
      <sales_order_place_after>
          <observers>
              <company_Mpassignproduct_Model_Observer>
              <type>singleton</type>
              <class>company_Mpassignproduct_Model_Observer</class>
              <method>afterPlaceOrder1</method>
              </company_Mpassignproduct_Model_Observer>
          </observers>
      </sales_order_place_after>
      <mp_delete_product>
          <observers>
              <mp_delete_product_isassign>
                  <type>singleton</type>
                  <class>company_Mpassignproduct_Model_Observer</class>
                  <method>deleteProductCheck</method>
              </mp_delete_product_isassign>
          </observers>
      </mp_delete_product>
    </events>
        <models>
            <mpassignproduct>
                  <class>company_Mpassignproduct_Model</class>
                  <resourceModel>mpassignproduct_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </mpassignproduct>
            <mpassignproduct_mysql4>
                <class>company_Mpassignproduct_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <mpassignproduct>
                        <table>marketplace_assignproduct</table>
                    </mpassignproduct>
                    <productshipping>
                        <table>marketplace_mpassign_shipping</table>
                    </productshipping>
                </entities>
            </mpassignproduct_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <mpassignproduct_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>company_Mpassignproduct</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </mpassignproduct_setup>
            <mpassignproduct_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </mpassignproduct_write>
            <mpassignproduct_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </mpassignproduct_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <mpassignproduct>
                <class>company_Mpassignproduct_Block</class>
            </mpassignproduct>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <mpassignproduct>
                <class>company_Mpassignproduct_Helper</class>
            </mpassignproduct>
        </helpers>
        <template>
            <email>
                <approveassignproduct>
                    <label>Approve My Product</label>
                    <file>mpassignproduct/admininformnewpro.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </approveassignproduct>
            </email>
        </template>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: What are the events that trigger the observer?

Comment: sorry, i did't got. i dont have much idea about this.

Comment: Ok, so edit your question and post the config.xml of your extension. Events are defined there.

Comment: please check updated question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your code here

```
$diff=$avlqty-$current_qty;
```

$diff is less then zero. So it will give you an error "Number of quantity not available".

Comment: is i need to remove this code ?

Comment: please debug variable $avlqty and $current_qty so you will get exact point of error

Comment: in checkout its checking the main configurable product quantity, its not checking the associative product quantity. i guess that is the reason ,its not allowing to increase the quantity. so please help me change the code, such that in it should check associative products quantity.

Comment: please try with  $cart_data =  Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAlltems();

Comment: just for a min, i am checking.....

Comment: I have checked this is working have you changed?

Comment: yes, seems its working  i added your code replacing both lines, below  : "/*after update cart*/ "  and below /*after product added to cart*/ . is it required below both lines?

Comment: its working now, thanks a lot for your support......

Comment: i can awrd this bounty points after 16 hours, i will give after that.....

Answer (score 2):

i think there is quantity issue for product.Just update product in stock qty in admin and try update qty again.

Comment: i tried, but its not working....  i updated the associated products...

Comment: please remove below jquery script and call it under head.phtml or header.phtml

<script src="http://videomergerapp.com/skin/frontend/default/em0113/js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>

b'coz when we click on Plus button jquery error occure

Comment: okay,i will try that....